# Bootstrap grid image problem height elements

Tags: css, image, grid

I'm not very good in CSS, and so I don't know how to solve my problem. I've a grid images (you can see at https://i.stack.imgur.com/QWZsY.jpg). As you can see the first image (I selected) has useless white space below.

How can I move the image below so that there are 50px difference?

Actually I use these classes for my box:

```
col-sm-6 col-md-4
```

I'm using bootstrap as you can see.

The other divs inside the `col-sm-6 col-md-4` have the right height.

Thank you for your help!

Example box:

```
<div class="_00d7">
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
       <div data-id="11" data-score="4380" class="_4180">
            <a class="eac1">
                <img src="images/E8wfc3V4Azc.jpg">
            </a>
            <div class="_96ae">
                Punteggio immagine: <b>4380</b>.
            </div>
       </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
._00d7 ._4180 {
    padding: 0;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    background-color: #fff;
    border-radius: 4px;
    border: none;
    transition: 0.15s ease-in-out;
    box-shadow: 0 8px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.06);
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0975);
}

._00d7 .eac1 img {
    border-radius: 4px 4px 0 0;
    vertical-align: middle;
    border-style: none;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    display: block;
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
```

(sorry for classes names, I'm using react)

Comment: did you set height for col-sm-6 col-md-4?

Comment: hi, I got this if I add max-height: 50px to col-sm-6 col-md-4 https://i.imgur.com/Tvd9A1Y.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For that particular layout (a [Mansonry](https://masonry.desandro.com/)-like layout) Bootstrap4 give you a solution: use **Card columns**: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/card/#card-columns.

I give you an example. This is only a start point, you can customize as you want.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="_00d7">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
       <div class="col-sm-12">
          <div class="card-columns">
             <div data-id="11" data-score="4380" class="_4180 card">
                  <a class="eac1">
                      <img class="card-img-top" src="https://picsum.photos/200/500">
                  </a>
                  <div class="_96ae card-body">
                      <p class="card-text">Punteggio immagine: <b>4380</b>.</p>
                  </div>
             </div>
     
             <div data-id="11" data-score="4380" class="_4180 card">
                  <a class="eac1">
                      <img class="card-img-top" src="https://picsum.photos/200/250">
                  </a>
                  <div class="_96ae card-body">
                      <p class="card-text">Punteggio immagine: <b>4380</b>.</p>
                  </div>
             </div>
    
             <div data-id="11" data-score="4380" class="_4180 card">
                  <a class="eac1">
                      <img class="card-img-top" src="https://picsum.photos/200/300">
                  </a>
                  <div class="_96ae card-body">
                      <p class="card-text">Punteggio immagine: <b>4380</b>.</p>
                  </div>
             </div>
       
             <div data-id="11" data-score="4380" class="_4180 card">
                  <a class="eac1">
                      <img class="card-img-top" src="https://picsum.photos/200/100">
                  </a>
                  <div class="_96ae card-body">
                     <p class="card-text"> Punteggio immagine: <b>4380</b>.</p>
                  </div>
             </div>
     
             <div data-id="11" data-score="4380" class="_4180 card">
                  <a class="eac1">
                      <img class="card-img-top" src="https://picsum.photos/200/300">
                  </a>
                  <div class="_96ae card-body">
                     <p class="card-text"> Punteggio immagine: <b>4380</b>.</p>
                  </div>
             </div>
           </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Be careful**: the images order is vertical:

```
1 4 7 
2 5 8
3 6 9
```

Comment: Love you. I didn't remember about Mansonry too! The card is perfect to do the job!

Grazie ;)

Comment: You're welcome, it was a pleasure! Eh, cosa vuoi, quelli di Bootstrap le hanno pensate tutte ;-)

Comment: È tutto responsive anche, fantastico! (Preferisco il back-end, con la grafica ci faccio a botte purtroppo)

Comment: Sì sì, un gioiellino. (Ad ognuno il suo: vedessi i ko che mi becco io col php...)